# Java Version Troubles on Raspbian (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: debian, raspbian, java, signal-messenger

I'd like to use [signal-cli](https://github.com/AsamK/signal-cli) to send some signal messages from my Pi-based cat feeder. I believe I've followed the installation steps correctly. When I try to run the command, I get the error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/asamk/signal/Main 
has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), 
this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [...]
```

When I run `apt list --installed | grep jre`, I get these results:

```
default-jre/oldoldstable,now 2:1.8-58+deb9u1+b3 armhf [installed]
default-jre-headless/oldoldstable,now 2:1.8-58+deb9u1+b3 armhf [installed,automatic]
openjdk-8-jre/oldoldstable,now 8u322-b06-1~deb9u1 armhf [installed]
openjdk-8-jre-headless/oldoldstable,now 8u322-b06-1~deb9u1 armhf [installed,automatic]
```

I ran `apt-get install --only-upgrade [packagename]` on default-jre and openjdk-8-jre, and it did some work to bring them up to the latest version. But the error running signal-cli persists. What can I do to make this command line tool run without error?

Comment: You need java 11. Either upgrade to oldstable or actually compile the software (don't use the release binary) from java 8 to use java 8. Anyway the readme writes as requirement: Java 17. That means using stable (not oldoldstable or oldstable). Also reading further, there's also this to ponder: https://github.com/AsamK/signal-cli/wiki/Provide-native-lib-for-libsignal

Comment: Thanks for the information @A.B I apologize for my inexperience, but how do I do that?

Comment: Additional complication: I've been googling and trying various things. I now see it's worth noting that I'm on Raspbian Stretch.